# Page 404 on reloading Vue.js app running in Tomcat

Tags: vue.js, tomcat, vuejs3, http-status-code-404

Our webapp has its backend running on Java Spring and front end on Vue.js. Both are hosted in Tomcat (webapps folder). The backend is inside 'ROOT' folder, and front end is inside 'front' folder inside Webapps dir.

As vue front end is SPA, when we reload the app, we get a 404 as the server isn't able to find appropriate location from the reload URL. What settings should I change in Tomcat so that the reload works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check to see which part of your 404 error is from tomcat or java and then look for the command to tell it to redirect the 404 address to /front.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The error seems to be from Tomcat itself. I tried editing the web.xml file to redirect 404 to a custom page, but it isn't working. I'm using Apache tomcat 9.0.56.